# php security of mail funciton

Tags: php, security

PHP zce exam study guide says

> Your PHP application sends an email with data provided by the user, using PHP's mail() function. How can an attacker inject a custom BCC header to that email?

```
A: Adding "\rBcc: email@example.com" to the subject
B: Adding "\nBcc: email@example.com" to the mail body
C: Adding "\r\nBcc: email@example.com" to the sender's address
D: None of the above
```

Correct answer: D: None of the above

Can anyone explain why "C" is not correct answer?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: What makes you believe that C is the right answer?

Comment: check https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and you will find the answer yourself (tip: example #4)

Comment: @MarkBaker As the sender's address is set in the additional headers, it would seem that is the place to inject the bcc. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @u_mulder Must be a language thing then, I understand the sender to be the "from" address, not the recipient / to address...

Comment: @Edwin I have read the example #4 carefully and it illustrates that answer "C" should be correct as jeroen says

Comment: Could this be a question typo? Might they had meant `'\r\nBcc: email@example.com'` or maybe `recipient's address`?

Comment: ok, now I see, I've tested it with `'` (as in manual), not with `"`

Comment: Thank you for answers we made some experiments with colleagues and find the answer. I have wrote the answer to the post.

Comment: Thank you @AlexandraFedotova.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is actually D because "\r\n" characters are not interpreted when provided from user input.

Some examples to illustrate: Giving the following code:

```
$headers = "From: from@example.com{$_GET['q']}";
$result = mail('test@example.com', 'subject', 'message', $headers);
```

Providing via get parameter: http://example.com?q="\r\nBcc:%20test2@example.com" will not work. But this will work: http://example.com?q=%0D%0ABcc:%20test2@example.com